# android emulator continuously showing a log cat message

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-emulator

I'm using **Eclipse** for **android** developments and very recently I updated **SDK** and **ADT**. And now when I'm starting **emulator** to run a project, it goes offline number of time and i had had to rerun the apps several time. And when the emulator launched and while my projects are running i continuously getting a log cat message as following.

```
12-04 10:54:49.454: W/Trace(9827): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Is this because of some wrong with my SDK or emulator. I remove some android versions and reinstall them. but no rusalt got.

How can I fix this. Help me. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDK uptation may corrupt your existing file.So you download new SDK bundle for your platform from the following link.
      https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.